# secure json data transfer?

Tags: c#, web-services, json

I have bunch of screens (asp.net C#) capturing data and transferring it back to a web service using json.

How can i encrypt content like passwords and decrypt it back in the C# code?

Comment: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020312.htm

Answer (score 0):

passwords are usually encrypted in an asymetric fashion (ie they can't be decrypted) so that's not what you want...

What's your problem ?

I you just want to be sure the data comes from your app and not some random evil guy a *signature* would be enough.

If you want nobody to intercept your data why not use HTTPS ?

Comment: Indeed, if the web service accepts HTTPS than the entire transaction would be encrypted, without much complex coding.